# PHP How can I print an array inside a csv file?

Tags: php, arrays

I cannot find a way to print the content of an Array sent by Jquery to a Php script and write on a file. I tried everything printr_r($array,true) but it writes also all the stuff I don't wanna see (eg. the keyword Array, the '=>' symbols and so on..). I tried also foreach but it writes on the file only "Array".

Here is the jquery:

```
 table.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {

        arrProva = [value];

        alert(arrProva); // it reads all the elements properly!

        $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',               
                  url:'exportREPORTS_SA_Filtered.php',
                  data: { ok: 1, arrayFiltrato: arrProva },
                  success: function(msg) {
                            alert('Tutto ok: ' + msg)
                  }, error: function(err) {
                                            alert('Errore ' + err);
                                          }
                      });
            });
```

And the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['ok']) && ($_POST['ok'] == 1)) {
     $arrayRicevuto = array($_POST['arrayFiltrato']);
    //$arrayRicevuto = implode(" ",$arrayRicevuto);
    $data = date("dmY");
    $filename = "EstrazioneParziale_del_" . $data;
    $estensione = ".csv";
    $fileOpen = fopen($filename.$estensione, "a") or die("Impossibile aprire il file");
    foreach($arrayRicevuto as  $value){
        fwrite($fileOpen,$value."\t");
    }
    fclose($file); }
```

Please help me, I am getting crazy.

Comment: have you tried using fputcsv http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: I SOLVED FOLLOWING YOUR SUGGESTION (php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and putting directly the $_POST['arrayFiltrato'] Superglobal Variable inside the foreach! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using json_decode instead of array() while declaring the array.

Instead of:

```
$arrayRicevuto = array($_POST['arrayFiltrato']);
```

Use:

```
$arrayRicevuto = json_decode($_POST['arrayFiltrato']);
```

Comment: thank you but I followed the suggestion of tuckbloor :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array to string using `implode` function like below.

```
 $arrayRicevuto = implode(" ", $_POST['arrayFiltrato']);
```